# No moves at all, not even to put yourself in check

Tags: chess, construction

[image: stalemate max]

Here, white is stalemated. The king is not in check, but white has no legal moves. Not because any move white makes would put the king in check -- which is how stalemates normally happen -- *but because no white piece can move at all, even if we temporarily ignore the no-self-check rule*.

(Black is not stalemated: king takes bishop.)

Now, this example is a bit wasteful, 62 white pieces plus the two kings. Also, it can't be reached from the starting position.

Come up with an example, using the fewest pieces (total both sides). Can it actually be reached from the starting position?

Small hint:

> <s>there is essentially only one answer</s>. [EDIT: OP screwed up]

Comment: If I'm black in the above example, I think I'm happy with the draw.

Comment: Now for another challenge: produce a legal position where *both* sides are likewise stalemated [so that even being forced to move into check would be a loss, and a player could pass if no pieces could move at all, the game would be drawn].

Comment: @supercat - if you want to post part 2, go for it!

Comment: @deepthought: I actually did, quite some time ago, but on a different SE board: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4836/is-it-possible-to-have-a-double-self-smothered-stalemate

Comment: @supercat - ah nice, thanks for the link

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are my first idea (both sides are essentially the same answer, so the hint fits too):

> [image]

Both positions seem to be independently reachable by a legal game. It might be possible to find a legal game leading to the whole position too, but that would take a bit of time.

Before that, I'm going to double check for any simpler solutions. :-)

Since OP commented that only one side needs to be stalemated in this rigorous fashion, this should do the trick:

> [image]

Comment: White needs to have promoted 4 pawns, no? There are only 3 white pawns missing.

Comment: Note only one side needs to be stalemated

Comment: oops, there are too many same coloured bishops. Imagine the G and H files swapped for a more reachable position please :-)

Comment: +1 but still not minimal!

Comment: Now you got it. The only other option is .. the other corner.

Comment: Ummm, black is in check now...

Comment: Yeah, you are too quick, I immediately deleted that one

Comment: Aaah I forgot to use black pieces... Nice work @Bass!

Comment: I think there's another 6+1 solution, given in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

How about

> [image]

I think that's an alternative 6+1-piece solution.

Comment: Before posting the puzzle I proved my solution was unique [OP vanishes in a puff of logic]

Comment: I'll award a bonus, but it looks like there's a delay enforced.

Answer (score 6):

The general idea is

> To fill the 8th rank with major pieces which block pawns from advancing, and fill the 7th rank with pawns which block the pieces from moving. We can't have knights on the 8th, though, because they would still have 6th rank squares available.

Here's a solution with 14 pieces total.

> Promote three pawns to two rooks and a bishop.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Correct +1, but not minimal!

Comment: @deepthought got it down to 13 :)

Comment: great! but keep going :-D