# A position where both sides have no moves at all, not even to put yourself in check

Tags: chess, construction

Inspired by this: [No moves at all, not even to put yourself in check](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74138/no-moves-at-all-not-even-to-put-yourself-in-check)

Similar to the question linked above, find an arrangement using the fewest chess pieces (total from both sides), except for this question both sides have to be immobilized.
In other words, find a minimal arrangement of pieces such that neither white nor black would be able to move even if it were legal to put yourself in check.

Comment: The accepted answer of the linked question also contains an answer to this one. Are you claiming that it is not minimal? Unfortunately, if that answer is correct then strictly speaking this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Actually, in the comments of the linked question it says that this two-sided version of the question was asked over on Chess SE. I took a look, and the answer there shows that there is a better solution to the problem than is found on Puzzling SE. So I take back my previous comment, and urge anyone who wants to solve this problem not to look on Chess SE.

Comment: Considering the 64 piece start of the linked question: Must the position be legal, esp: Are pawns on the 1st/8th row allowed?

Answer (score 5):

Here is one with 15 pieces. As far as I can tell it is a legal reachable position, although I do not give a proof game.

> [image]

Note: After posting this I did take a look at the chess SE solution @Jaap mentions in the comments and it is essentially the same. And they have a proof game.